# Backend API for accepting crypto payment like Coinbase commerce

Tags: node.js, blockchain

I want to create a personal crypto gateway REST API with simple actions like Coinbase Commerce via Nodejs from scratch and not using Coinbase Commerce API or other third-party company. I want to generate ready-to-pay addresses for BTC, ETH, LTC, USDT on my client payment requests with implemented local amount for each network like. Something like these requests schema:

```
POST /generateAddressesToPay   [accepting parameters: myWalletAddress, amountToPay]
    return: {
         btc: {
            addressToPay: 'XXXXXXXXX',
            amountInSatochi: 0.00425
         },
         ltc: {
            addressToPay: 'XXXXXXXXX',
            amountInSatochi: 0.00425
         },
         etc...
    }

GET /ListOfTransactio    [accepting parameters: network, 'ltc', totalRetrive: 10, wallet: 'XXXXXXXXX']
GET /TransactionStatus    [accepting parameters: network, 'ltc', exID, 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX']
```

I searched a lot. For example for ETH, I fond Web3.js but I don't understand how to generate Wallet, and then ready-to-pay address for an specific payment transacting.

It would be nice if you give me some links that I can see examples of payment gateway in nodejs for each blockchain that I mentioned. Something understandable and focused on payment gateway actions.